# Empty screenshots on Google Page Insights

Tags: google, google-search-console

Our page has a 100 rating for Desktop in Google Page Insights. This is expected because the page only has the word "Test" on it.

However, in the screenshots below (where Page Insights shows the loading process) the first screenshot is always empty. In the second screenshot, the word "test" is visible.

From my browser, the page loads instantly (as expected) even with a slow connection.

This is a strong dedicated server with 16GB of RAM (although this shouldn't come into play at all).

What could be causing this problem for Google? Could it be simply a matter of geolocation or something similar? We are using Cloudflare for DNS management.

How can I test and remedy this problem?

Comment: Why would that be a problem?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller It's not a problem for me as a dev but the client has a problem with it. Do you have some resource that can help me prove to him that it doesn't matter?

Comment: I would expect that to happen because tests that download a page remotely are NEVER going to be instant.

Comment: The thing is, some of our competitors don't have these empty screenshots. I know this is largely irrelevant but if I want to appease the client is there anything I could try? Load balancing? CDN?